# Where is "erd" and "dot" program?

Tags: django, extension, erd

[image]

I have problem in vscode ERD diagram preview. (As seen above print-screen my VSCode)

Have tried: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaishuu0123.vscode-erd-preview#configuration

**What is the meaning:**

> Make sure the extension can find the "erd" and "dot" program.

**Where is "erd" and "dot" program path? How can set:**

> You can set erd-preview.erdPath and erd-preview.dotPath option.

I have tried this in `settings.json`:

```
"erd-preview.erdPath": "C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin",
"erd-preview.dotPath": "C:/Program Files/Graphviz/bin"
```

Of course after installing https://www.graphviz.org/ from [windows setup](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaishuu0123.vscode-erd-preview#windows)

**Lastly, What is `erd-preview.erdPath` and `erd-preview.dotPath` values?**

Comment: Could you confirm graphviz is actually at that location?

Comment: Launch `cmd` with WinKey+R and then type `echo %PATH%` at the prompt, if you cannot see `graphviz` in the text that got displayed, then you MIGHT need to arrange it to be. `dot` is the graph rendering tool of https://graphviz.org/

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, Yes. I don't know what id difference of two "erd" path and "dot" path and get same value. Exactly have seen `dot.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin` path.

Comment: @Hannu, The `C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin;` is there in `echo %PATH%` string.

Comment: I think that `dotPath` is the path to `dot.exe`, which might be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz\bin\dot.exe`. Same for `erdPath` for `erd.exe`.

Comment: One more detail; this appears to be on Windows based on the use of `C:`, but `/` has a tendency to be "bad" in windows paths, might THAT be a problem here?

Comment: @Hannu: Seems no problem. Of course I found using `"erd-preview.erdPath": "C:\\Users\\user\\Tools\\windows_amd64_erd-go.exe"` in [visualstudio.com](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaishuu0123.vscode-erd-preview#windows). I was set everithings in this document, but as the picture above, not shows flowchart. Are there anyone have experience installing and using this extension in vscode?

Comment: I have download `windows_amd64_erd-go.exe` and `graphviz-dot-win-x64.exe` from desired GitHub link and copy them in `C:\Users\(user name)\Tools\` as mentioned above. But steel the diagram of erd file (`simpler.er`) not shown same as the above picture. I cant found what is the extension setting is missed!